# Cannot Liveview viewDidLoad on XCode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6, liveview

I started a project under XCode 5 for iOS7, then left it for a few weeks.

Now, I have upgraded to XCode 6 (and iOS8) and I would like to use the liveview function to see my viewDidLoad function.

So I added :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

It seems like the liveview changed from the beta to the final release of XCode6. It appears that you do not need to add your custom framework anymore.

But is it still limited to UIView ?

Or maybe I don't need to use UIViewControllers for my storyboard anymore and go full UIView ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You do still need to add a framework, as far as I know. I would love to be proven wrong if you have a link.
2. `IB_DESIGNABLE` currently works only with `UIView` subclasses as far as I know. I recommend still using view controllers where appropriate, but through judicious use of view controller containment, you can make lightweight, composable view controllers that contain `IB_DESIGNABLE` view elements.